# How to add custom fields for users (like Company:) in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, joomla, customization, joomla1.5

I've been searching on the internet for some kind of tutorial to do this and I've only found this one that seems to do the work ( http://tech.nabtron.com/add-custom-field-for-user-data-joomla-1-0-tested/97/ ) but the problem is that this tutorial is focused in Joomla 1.0 and I'm using Joomla 1.5.. the files are not in the same place and some classes are very different...

It will be great if you could point me to a web page where somebody explains how to do this..
Or if you are a Joomla expert help me with this please... I have some knowledge about php and mysql but I'm not familiar with the Joomla workflow.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Doh! I've forget to tell you that it's not necessary to show this custom field at the Back-End.. Just show it at registration and store it to the db.

Answer (score 1):

Have a Look at this Extension if you dont like to hard code it
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/5583

And here is the hard coding tutorial 
http://groups.google.com/group/joomlagrandrapids/browse_thread/thread/10d2610576fadab5

Comment: Thanks! The second link is exactly what I need but I need to add my custom field for users not the articles.

Now I have: Name, Username, Mail, Password
and I need to add: Company, Address, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I've found my solution in this page and a little bit of imagination.
It was pretty easy.. I thought it was more complicated.

http://jwarlock.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/9-adding-fields-to-joomla-registration-page.html

If you are in the same position as me and you don't understand the tutorial, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Cheers, Luis.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is Joomla Meta http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/usermeta/

It uses the same functionality (well similar to how it will be implemented in J1.6) and doesn't require any core hacks

It's been used on this site http://www.theabroadgroup.com/propertyabroad/index.php?option=com_user&view=register&Itemid=71